# Problema JSON.parse y JSON.stringify

Tags: array, json, vue.js, string

Cuando borro la cache y entro por primera vez en mi apartado, no funciona correctamente una variable que tiene almacenada una array.

Esta es la variable:
`let users = JSON.parse(localStorage['users'])`

Llama a esto:

```
  created() {
      axios.get(this.$URL +'factures/create').then((response) => {
              // console.log(response.data);
                this.users = response.data[0];
                this.machines = response.data[1];
                this.materials = response.data[2];
                let users = response.data[0];
                localStorage['users'] = JSON.stringify(users)

            });

  },
```

Cuando funciona correctamente y hago un console.log(users) me tiene que mostrar esto:
[image]

El problema es que si borro la cache y vuelvo a entrar me salta este error en la consola y no me carga la pagina:

```
app.js:61153 SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)     at Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/js/components/App/Invoice/CreateInvoice.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (resources_js_components_App_Invoice_CreateInvoice_vue.js:23:18)     at __webpack_require__ (app.js:63063:42)     at Module../resources/js/components/App/Invoice/CreateInvoice.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (resources_js_components_App_Invoice_CreateInvoice_vue.js:709:215)     at __webpack_require__ (app.js:63063:42)     at Module../resources/js/components/App/Invoice/CreateInvoice.vue (resources_js_components_App_Invoice_CreateInvoice_vue.js:683:100)     at Function.__webpack_require__ (app.js:63063:42)
```

Si cambio la variable users de manera que quede así (`let users = JSON.stringify(localStorage['users'])`  ) y vuelvo a entrar en la pagina, el error desaparece. Esto solo sirve para que arranque todo ya que necesito que me lo muestre como en la captura del console.log(users), por tanto lo que hago es volver a poner la variable así (`let users = JSON.parse(localStorage['users'])`  ) y ya esta, me funciona todo correctamente.

Pero claro esto no es una solucion, necesito que sin tener que cambiar la variable a stringify y luego a parse me funcione bien. Si alguien puede ayudarme a ver que estoy haciendo mal seria de agradecer. :D

Gracias.

Edit:

```
<script>

import {ref, computed} from 'vue'
let id;

  if('users' in localStorage){
     let users = JSON.parse(localStorage['users'])
   }else{
       created()
   }
export default {

    
data() {
    
    return {
      invoices: [],
      invoicerow: [],
      users: [],
       machines: [],
        materials: []  
    };
  },
  
  created() {
      axios.get(this.$URL +'factures/create').then((response) => {
              // console.log(response.data);
                this.users = response.data[0];
                this.machines = response.data[1];
                this.materials = response.data[2];
                let users = response.data[0];
                localStorage['users'] = JSON.stringify(users)

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

fijate si evaluando con un if si el localstorage existe y actuando en consecuencia , que creo que en js es !LocalStorage.get("users"). Si no existe hay que crearlo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Como menciona Jorge en su repuesta tu problema es que no estas verificando que la clave users exista en localStorage antes de tratar de parsearla a Json, por eso muestra el error de 'Unexpected token u in JSON' donde u es el primer caracter al tratar de convertir a JSON la palabra undefined. debe solucionarse con una simple verificación y de no existir mandar a cargarla entonces.

```
   created() {
      if('users' in localStorage){
       this.users = JSON.parse(localStorage['users'])
     }else{
       //si no existe lo cargamos entonces del servidor
        axios.get(this.$URL +'factures/create').then((response) => {
                  this.users = response.data[0];
                  localStorage['users'] = JSON.stringify(this.users)
         });
      }
   }
```

Comment: ¿Donde deberia poner el if? He probado arriba del todo pero sale que created no esta definido. He puesto el codigo en la pregunta original.

Comment: Ajusté el codigo de la respuesta teniendo en cuenta tu edición, aqui solo contemplo la variable users.